# Sending ArrayList From android to SOAP and getting error: org.kxml2.kdom.Element.write(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer)

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, netbeans

I was testing an Android application which uses a KSOAP2 library and I'm trying to send an object ArrayList to my web service application which is in netbeans with a method who receive this List and return a response.

I was searching information about how to test the web service, because netbeans uses a default server (glassfish) and the netbeans project that I have uses tomcat, so I found the SOAP UI program to test this method and when I pass the list with the SOAP UI request, the method response is successful it should return a LIST of objects too, and that's ok from now BUT,

in Android I tried to send this ArrayList like this:

```
private final String SOAP_NAMESPACE = "http://ws.soap.net/";
private final String URL_SOAP="http://MI_IP:PORT/GetSomeRest/WebServiceTest";
private final String SOAP_SOMETHING = "GetSomething";
private final String SOAP_ACTION_GETSOMETHING = "http://ws.soap.net/" + SOAP_SOMETHING;
public SoapObject SendSigns(ArrayList<Signs> paramSigns)
{       
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(SOAP_NAMESPACE, SOAP_SOMETHING);

    request.addSoapObject(buildArray(paramSigns));

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    
    new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
    envelope.bodyOut = request;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
    envelope.implicitTypes= true;
    envelope.dotNet=true;
    envelope.headerOut = new org.kxml2.kdom.Element[1];
    
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_SOAP);

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_GETSOMETHING, envelope);
        
        SoapObject Object = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        
        if(Object!=null)
        {
            return Object;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("CALL DUMP", "requestError: "+androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
        Log.d("CALL DUMP", "responseEror: "+androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
        Log.e("ERROR: ", String.valueOf(e));

    }        
    return null;
}
```

Here is the buildArray Method which returns a SoapObject with the List filled:

```
protected SoapObject buildArray(ArrayList<Signs> paramSigns) {
  
    SoapObject soapSigns = new SoapObject(SOAP_NAMESPACE, "List");

    for (int i = 0; i < Signs.size(); i++) {
        paramSigns.addProperty("id",Signs.get(i).getId());
        paramSigns.addProperty("type",Signs.get(i).getType());
    }
    return soapSigns;
}
```

So when I run my application I got the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.kxml2.kdom.Element.write(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer)' on a null object reference

BUT IF,

If I delete this following line:

```
envelope.headerOut = new org.kxml2.kdom.Element[1];
```

I receive a response from web service, but with a soapObject Null, and I put this line:

```
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
```

And I saw the requestDump was filled with a XML like this:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
<v:Body>
<GetSomething xmlns="http://ws.soap.net/">
<List>
<id>386661006</id>
<tipo>sign</tipo>
<id>68235000</id>
<tipo>sign</tipo>
<id>25064002</id>
<tipo>sign</tipo>
</List>
</GetSomething>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

And I paste this XML in the SOAP UI request and I didn't have a response...

So how could I face the java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.kxml2.kdom.Element.write(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer)' on a null object reference?

I would be grateful by all kind of help!

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, the problem was precisely this line:

```
envelope.headerOut = new org.kxml2.kdom.Element[1];
```

Because i think that my Web Service doesn't have a Header!

That was the way to avoid the error...

Best regards!